# accessing form data in one jsp from another jsp

Tags: jsp, struts2, tiles2

I am using Struts 2 and Tiles to develop an application.

I have 2 JSP files being loaded into 2 separate cells of a table (Tiles concept). The first JSP has links (created using `<s:url/>` tag). Clicking on these links should:

(a) retrieve the current form data (the value selected in a radio button group, the values selected in a checkbox group and the value in a textfield) in the second JSP and update the database,

(b) Then different data has to be fetched to populate the second JSP.

How do I achieve (a)?

Comment: Probably the easiest way would be to use the id and class attributes to set workable names, for which a JS library such as jQuery could manipulate.

Answer (score -1):

In the `s:form` tag, specify an `action`. The form will be submitted to this Action class. It must also contain setters for each of your form fields. You can then process the user submitted data in that action's `execute` method.

Answer (score -1):

You can try using ajax instead of tiles. You'll have to combine the first and second JSP into a single JSP though.